# How Do You Automatically Give Players An Item When They Kill Another User?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I am working on a PVP thing in my server and I am trying to figure out how to make it so that when you kill someone, you get an emerald that you can use for shops. I can't figure out how to make the emerald thing work though.

This is what I tried:

- 1st I did `/scoreboard objectives add KillScore playerKillCount`
- 2nd, I put these two commands on a redstone clock:

  - `give @a[score_KillScore_min=1] minecraft:emerald`
  - `scoreboard players remove @a[score_KillScore_min=1] KillScore 1`
- 3rd I activated the redstone clock, but when I kill another player,
  it does nothing.

Here is a screenshot of the clock I made: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: You can put everything in the loop into a chain of command blocks: First repeating, pointing into the second one, which is chain, pointing into the next chain command block, etc. Set all of them to "always active" and it will always run. No need for redstone nowadays.

Did you look at the output of your command blocks? They don't print errors in chat, you have to open them to see their result. You have a syntax error, the `/give` command is incomplete, it lacks the number of items. Change it to `give @a[score_KillScore_min=1] minecraft:emerald 1`

Edit: The count is not actually required. This should not have fixed it, but according to the asker, it did. I don't know why.